# Prenex Normal Form properties Inquiry

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

In my study of the Prenex Normal Form I encountered the following property about conjunctions with universal quantifiers:
$$\forall x(p\land q)\iff\forall x\ p\land\forall x\ q$$
This property seems to make sense if I apply Universal Instantiation.
I however encountered the following property about disjunctions with universal quantifiers that made me wonder why it doesn't use a biconditional connective like in the first formula? It goes as follows:
$$\forall x\ p\lor\forall x\ q\implies\forall x(p\lor q)$$
I would have guessed that, using Universal Instantiation just as in the first formula, it would have also a biconditional connective instead of a mere conditional one.
I found the same exact question with conjunctions of existential quantifiers
$$\exists x(p\land q)\implies\exists x\ p\land\exists x\ q$$
and disjunctions with existential quantifiers
$$\exists x(p\lor q)\iff\exists x\ p\lor\exists x\ q$$
Shouldn't all be biconditionals?
Your help, as always, will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that we can read your mathematics in line.

Comment: No; not all hold in both ways. Example: "Every number is (either Even or Odd)" is True while Either (every number is Even) or (every number is Odd)" is False.

Answer (score 1):

Every number is either odd or even, but "at least one of the following holds: (1) all numbers are odd; (2) all numbers are even" is certainly false.

$\exists x(p\land q)\Rightarrow \exists xp\land\exists xq$ is basically the contraposition of $\forall xp\lor\forall xq\Rightarrow\forall x(p\lor q)$. That is why only one direction holds in both cases.